# entity content is too long [658121477] for the configured buffer limit [104857600]

Tags: elasticsearch, resthighlevelclient

Exception occurred when performing Search operation on Elastic indexes with really large data.
Using RestHighLevelClient to perform Search with Http method as RequestOptions.DEFAULT

Error Logs:
error is :  java.io.IOException: entity content is too long [658121477] for the configured buffer limit [104857600]\n\tat org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.extractAndWrapCause(RestClient.java:886)

my restclient is:

RestHighLevelClient restHighLevelClient = null;
final CredentialsProvider credentialsProvider =   new BasicCredentialsProvider();
credentialsProvider.setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY,
new UsernamePasswordCredentials(userName, passWord));
RestClientBuilder builder = RestClient.builder(
HttpHost.create(host))
.setHttpClientConfigCallback(httpClientBuilder -> httpClientBuilder
.setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider));
restHighLevelClient = new RestHighLevelClient(builder);

Answer (score 0):

The maximum number of bytes you can send in an HTTP query is configured in [`http.max_content_length`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-network.html#http-settings) to be 104857600 (i.e. 100mb).

As you are sending six times as many bytes (i.e. 658121477), you're getting an exception. You now have two options:

A. you increase the `http.max_content_length` setting, but it's risky because you run the risk of overloading your cluster

B. you split your payload into 6 or 7 smaller chunks that fit into 100mb.